# Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.1si1c.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This error is showing up when I am trying to connect nodejs to mongodb atlas. Everything is fine and then it is happening:

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.1si1c.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'cluster0.1si1c.mongodb.net'
}
```

Comment: Is your url correct and in this format? `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.1si1c.mongodb.net/<database_name>`

Comment: const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.1si1c.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

I did it this way

Comment: Is your environment variables loaded before the `mongoose.connect()`?

Comment: Loading when I'm doing console.log
But I do not understand what the problem is.